# Best way to add rounded corners to a triangle in OpenGL ES 2+ on iOS

Tags: opengl-es, geometry, opengl-es-2.0, polygon, rounded-corners

When drawing filled, no outline triangles with OpenGL ES 2+ is there a way to easily add rounded corners to the triangles?

Is it also performant or is there a need to do it in a more complex manner to get performant rounded corners on a triangle?

// think dynamic triangles.  And dynamic ability to adjust the radius of the corners would be useful also.

The only way I can think of is stepping around the corner, but I'm hoping there's an easy effect or some other magical less intensive effort required to pull it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut to doing this. Adding rounded corners to a triangle means it is not a triangle any more, so cannot be rendered as a single primitive.

Instead it needs to be constructed out of many triangles to give the illusion of a smooth rounded corner. So your own suggestion about 'stepping around the corner' is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Do you / anybody know an efficient algorithm to "convert" the edge vertices of a polygon to a set of triangles that represent that polygon + rounded corners? So that you can draw it with GL_TRIANGLES ?

Comment: A rounded triangle would be convex, so if you have the edge vertices of your rounded triangle stored in clockwise order, the indices you could use are  (tri 1) 0,1,2  (tri 2) 0,2,3  (tri 3) 0,3,4  (tri 4) 0,4,5  etc....